# Get the Index of an Element in a List in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How can the index of the elements in a list be calculated in Terraform?

Example:
If we have this variable:

```
variable "domains" {

  type = "list"

  default = [
    "tftesting.io",
    "tftesting.co",
  ]
}
```

How can we calculate that "tftesting.io" has index "0" and "tftesting.co" has index "1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the winner is: `index(list, element)`

```
variable "domains" {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "tftesting.io",
    "tftesting.co",
  ]
}

output "co_index" {
  value = "${index(var.domains, "tftesting.co")}"
}

output "io_index" {
  value = "${index(var.domains, "tftesting.io")}"
}
```

The end result:

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

co_index = 1
io_index = 0
```